# why two routes calling same page in react js that has different path link

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

<Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name/:name`} component={Modals}/>
<Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name`} component={Companies}/>

when call second route this is calling very well. but when am call first route first route and second route both are calling. please solve my issue.

Comment: What is calling, or being called? `Route` components don't call things. Where are these routes being rendered?

Comment: You should add `exact` to be called separately .

Answer (score 0):

Use `Switch` to render the Routes Exclusively and use `exact` to strictly match the pattern

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";

let routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route path={${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name/:name} component={Modals} exact />
    <Route path={${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name} component={Companies} exact />
  </Switch>
);
```

Refer: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

Comment: i already use switch or full syntex of routing for render the routes. but problem is there that both rout is call when i click the link of second route that you can see the below.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Switch><Route path={${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name/:name} exact component={Modals}/> 
<Route path={${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name} exact component={Companies}/> </Switch>
```

You should add **exact** and **Switch** to your routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering the routes into a `Router` they both can be matched and rendered. The `Router` ***inclusivley*** matches and renders routes. Use the `exact` prop to exactly match one or the other. The issue is that `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name` is a prefix for `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name/:name`, and so will also be matched.

```
<Route
  exact
  path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name/:name`}
  component={Modals}
/>
<Route
  exact
  path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name`}
  component={Companies}
/>
```

The alternative is to render the routes into a `Switch` to ***exclusively*** match and render routes. Here path order and specificity matter. Order your routes from most specific to least specific. You don't need to specify the `exact` prop since the `Switch` only matches and renders the first matching `Route`.

```
<Switch>
  ...
  <Route
    path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name/:name`}
    component={Modals}
  />
  <Route
    path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/book-repair/:name`}
    component={Companies}
  />
  ...
</Switch>
```